# Como fazer para imprimir os alunos que tiveram a media maior que 7

Tags: c, array

Faça um Programa que peça as quatro notas de 10 alunos, calcule e
armazene num vetor a média de cada aluno, imprima o número de alunos com
média maior ou igual a 7.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float notas[4];
   float media[10];
   int n;
   int a;
   
   for(a = 0; a < 3; a++){
    printf("Informe as notas do %i aluno", a + 1);
   
   for(n = 0; n < 4; n++){
   printf("\nNotas: ");
   scanf("%f", &notas[n]);
   media[a] = (notas[n] / n);
   
   }
   
   }
   for(a = 0; a < 10; a++){
    if(media[a] >= 7){
    
   printf("A media do %d aluno e: %.1f",a+1, media[a]);
   } 
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá Breno, pelo visto você é novo no Stackoverflow, para deixar claro, aqui não é um lugar onde você deve colocar o exercício para ser respondido, o interessante aqui é você mostrar o que fez, dizer talvez onde está o problema e pedir ajuda na questão da lógica e regra de negócio, mas a sua postagem está ao contrário disso.
Te convido para ler [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

O único ponto a ser acrescentado para que você consiga, é guardar o somatório das notas para faze o cálculo da média, se você olhar bem em `media[a] = (notas[n]/n)`, você sempre está atribuindo em cima o valor e nunca acontecerá um somatório, para fazer isso, você precisa basicamente fazer um `media[a] += (notas[n] / n);`
Deixei um repositório no github para consultas caso queira ver
[Imprimir alunos com média maior que 7.](https://github.com/vagnerwentz/stackoverflow/blob/main/ImprimirAlunosMediaMaiorQue7/main.c)

Para aproveitar bem, leia o código e tente entender, faça modificações caso queira ver o que cada variável ou declaração faça, assim consegue aprender melhor e se tornar um desenvolvedor de ponta.

## Resolução

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float notas[4];
  float media[10];
  float resultadoDaMedia = 0;
  float somatorioDasNotas = 0;
  int n, a;
   
  for(a = 0; a < 3; a++)
  {
    printf("Informe as notas do %i° aluno", a + 1);
   
    for(n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
      printf("\nNota %d: ", n + 1);
      scanf("%f", &notas[n]);
      somatorioDasNotas += notas[n];
      printf("\n%f", somatorioDasNotas);
    }
    media[a] += somatorioDasNotas / n;
    printf("\n%f", media[a]);
    somatorioDasNotas = 0;
  }

  for(a = 0; a < 10; a++) 
  {
    if(media[a] >= 7) 
    {
      printf("A media do %d aluno e: %.1f\n", a+1, media[a]);
    } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: obg me ajudou bastante aqui, eu só queria mesmo saber oq eu estava fazendo de errado nesta questão.

Comment: @BrenoAlmeida caso tenha te ajudado e você considera como resposta correta, você pode marcar minha resposta como a correta, agradeceria.